# Plotting ROC curve in cross validation using Matlab perfcurve

Tags: classification, cross-validation, matlab, plotting

I have the following code for a binary classifying using SVM, and 10 cross-validation,

```
k=10;
cp = classperf(lables); 
cvFolds = crossvalind('Kfold', lables, k);   
 for i = 1:k                                 
  testIdx = (cvFolds == i);                %# get indices of test instances
  trainIdx = ~testIdx;                     %# get indices training instances


   svmModel = fitcsvm(data_features(trainIdx,:), lables(trainIdx), 
   'Standardize',true,'KernelFunction','RBF','KernelScale','auto');

  pred = predict(svmModel, data_features(testIdx,:));
  cp = classperf(cp, pred, testIdx);
end
acc= cp.CorrectRate;
conf= cp.CountingMatrix;
```

I want to Plot the ROC curve using the  `perfcurve` function  in Matlab, However, the input 'score' changes each fold and can't be used outside the k-fold loop.

`[X,Y] = perfcurve(labels,scores,posclass)`

Any suggestion on how to plot a ROC in such case?